# how to get ajax form submit return value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I use ajax to submit a form, however when i finished the whole process, it stopped at the api.php and did get back to the ajax success. 
Here the code:

```
<form method="POST" id="form_1" action="../api.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Amy" readonly="readonly">
  <input id="fileBox" class="fileUpload" type="file" name="img" accept="image/*" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="isSubmit" value="1"/>
</form>

<a id="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Submit</a>
```

```
$("#form_1").submit(function(){
  var formData = new FormData(($this)[0]);
  $ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../api.php",
    data: { action:"formSubmit", formData:formData},
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(){
      console.log('success return');
    }
  })
});

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
  if($("#form_1").valid()){ 
    // inside click event handler you trigger form submission
    $("#form_1").trigger('submit');
  }
});
```

in my api.php

```
if($action=='formSubmit'){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  if(createUser($name)){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

I checked the database , record is successfully created. But I can't get the console in success. The url show on the browser there is the path of the api.php. Why I stopped there can't get the return?

Thanks for your help!!

I finallly did it !I am missing "return false" after the ajax; But actually I dont really know the function of return false;

```
$("#form_1").submit(function(){
var formData = new FormData((this)[0]);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../../api.php",
data: { action: "formSubmit",  formData: formData},
processData:false,
contentType:false,
success: function(data){
$("#thankyou").show();
}
})
return false;  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Redirecting to other page will have the `header()` to use:

```
if ($action == 'formSubmit') {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  if (createUser($name)) {
    // Redirect to right.htm
    header("Location: right.htm");
  } else {
    // Redirect to wrong.htm
    header("Location: wrong.htm");
  }
  die();
}
```

Comment: but now i really echo a text 'true' in the api.php and didn't go back to the form page

Comment: No. still stay at api.php

Comment: after submit in index.php then landed to api.php and echo the text 'true'

Comment: @SFY What exactly wanted it to happen. Give `return false` after `$("#form_1").trigger('submit');`.

Comment: redirect to another page if false. if true, then show div

Comment: @SFY Have a look now and let me know if it works. So if the output is `true`, it redirects to `right.htm`. If not, `wrong.htm`.

Comment: do you me 
`if($action=='formSubmit'){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  if(createUser($name)){
   //rediect to right.html
  }else{
    //redirect to wrong.html
  }
}`

Comment: Yes, that's what the code does. Copy and try first.

Comment: What? I don't understand. It redirects.

Comment: I try what ur mention above, i fall into true case, then it redirected to the right.html

Comment: I got the answer finally!! I am missing "return false;" after the ajax

Comment: Still got some problem with the submission. I ask a new question which describe more detail
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029910/ajax-form-submit-flow-is-not-correct

Comment: @SFY I thought you should be using the `e.preventDefault()`. Anyway, that is also a good method.

Answer (score 1):

javascript doesn't recognize return value from php. Use `echo` instead.

```
if($action=='formSubmit'){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if(createUser($name)){
       echo 'true';
    }else{
       echo 'false';
    }
}
```

If you want to see actual output coming from `api.php` then use below code in your `ajax`.

```
success: function(res){
   console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: I used echo but the stay at the api.php instead of the form page

Comment: What do you mean by stay at the `api.php`?

Comment: after submit in index.php then landed to api.php

Comment: and echo the text 'true';

Comment: That means you are not into the `ajax` call. Try to put `alert("here");` just below this line: `$("#form_1").submit(function(){`.