# Ajax form submit flow is not correct

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I submit the form when trigger submit. How ever I cannot create user record. I show you the code.

```
<form method="POST" id="form_1" action="../api.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Amy" readonly="readonly">
  <input id="fileBox" class="fileUpload" type="file" name="img" accept="image/*" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="isSubmit" value="1"/>
</form>

<a id="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Submit</a>
```

In js file:

```
$('#form_1').submit(function(){
  var formData = new FormData((this)[0]);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../api.php",
    data: { action: "isSubmit",  formData: formData},
    processData:false,
    contentType:false,
    success: function(data){
      $("#thankyou").show();
    }
  })
  return false;
});

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
  var name = $("#name").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../api.php",
    data: { action: "checkInputData",  name: name}
  })
    .done(function(data){
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    if ( data.status == 0 ){
      $('#form_1').trigger('submit');               
    }
```

api.php :

```
if( $action == "isSubmit"){
  $name= isset($_POST["name"])?$_POST["name"]:null; 
  createUser($conn, $name);
}
```

I found the the flow of the submit is not correct.
The flow of the above code is when I trigger submit then fall into success show thankyou div, but didn't create user record.

however if I removed the "return false" in ajax, the flow will becomes : trigger submit then fall into success show thankyou div then redirected to api.php then finished. In this case I can create the user record.

My target result should be I trigger submit then fall into success show thankyou div and create user record. How can I do this? And what's the differnce between having and without the "return false".

Comment: hi, try using this plugin, http://malsup.com/jquery/form/.  This will save you a lot of time and headache in ajax form submit. If your issue doesn't resolve please let me know.

Comment: thankyou for your suggestion. I prefer try to solve this problem first

Comment: have you tried `$(form).submit(function(e){e.preventDefault();});` instead of a `return false;` . Make sure you add the prevent default at top of the function start.

Comment: I tried 
`$('#form_1').submit(function(){
var formData = new FormData((this)[0]);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../../api.php",
data: { action: "isSubmit",  formData: formData},
processData:false,
contentType:false,
success: function(data){
$("#thankyou").show();
}
})
});`
stil the same , show the div but didn't create record

Comment: Use Dev Tools, debug, debug, show errors. You should use full relative path, not .../.../

Comment: First of all use preventDefault on button click. `$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();` and then your actual code. Then remove `return false;` from the ajax call.